# Timezone issue with Joda-time when converting a LocalTime to a DateTime using .toDateTime()

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime, localtime

I am writing some code to do periodic scheduling based based on time of day.  I am representing the regular schedule time of day as a Joda `LocalTime` object.  I then create event instances by converting the `LocalTime` to a `DateTime`.  When initially writing the code (and only scheduling events for "today") I used the `toDateTimeToday()` method on `LocalTime` and it worked as expected.  However when I switched to using the `toDateTime()` method to schedule events in the future I started seeing issues with mapping between UTC and local local timezone.

The following code demonstrates the problem I am seeing.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

LocalTime lt = new LocalTime(12,0);
System.out.println(" lt="+lt);

DateTime dtt = lt.toDateTimeToday();
System.out.println("dtt="+df.format(dtt.toDate()));

DateTime bdt = new DateTime();
System.out.println("bdt="+df.format(bdt.toDate()));

DateTime dt = lt.toDateTime(bdt.toInstant());
System.out.println(" dt="+df.format(dt.toDate()));
```

Here is the output:

```
 lt=12:00:00.000
dtt=2014-07-08T12:00:00-0400
bdt=2014-07-08T18:01:30-0400
 dt=2014-07-08T08:00:00-0400
```

As you can see, the `dtt` and `dt` should be the same time, but they are different by the local timezone offset.

### UPDATE

Based on Matt Johnson's answer, I made a simple change in my code, replacing:

```
DateTime dt = lt.toDateTime(bdt.toInstant());
```

with

```
DateTime dt = new LocalDate(bdt).toDateTime(lt);
```

My code updated with the change (plus switching to Joda formatting) is as follows:

```
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()));

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

LocalTime lt = new LocalTime(12,0);
System.out.println(" lt="+lt);

DateTime dtt = lt.toDateTimeToday();
System.out.println("dtt="+dtt.toString(fmt));

DateTime bdt = new DateTime();
System.out.println("bdt="+bdt.toString(fmt));

DateTime dt = new LocalDate(bdt).toDateTime(lt);
System.out.println(" dt="+dt.toString(fmt));
```

Here's the new (correct!!) output.

```
 lt=12:00:00.000
dtt=2014-07-09T12:00:00-0400
bdt=2014-07-09T00:15:35-0400
 dt=2014-07-09T12:00:00-0400
```

Thanks Matt!

Comment: Your results are being clouded by use of `toDate`.  Consider outputting using [Joda-Time's Formatters](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
LocalTime lt = new LocalTime(12, 0);        // the scheduled time
LocalDate ld = new LocalDate(2014, 7, 8);   // the day to run

DateTime dt = ld.ToDateTime(lt);
```

The above code will use the default time zone.  If your event is scheduled to run in a particular time zone, use:

```
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
DateTime dt = ld.ToDateTime(lt, tz);
```